# What's a good Lucene analyzer for text and source code?

Tags: html, search, lucene

What would be a good Lucene analyzer to use for documents that are a mix of text and diverse source code?

For example, I want "C" and "C++" to be considered different words, and I want `Charset.forName("utf-8")` to be split between the class name and method name, and for the parameter to be considered either one or two words.

A good example dataset for what I'd like to look at is StackOverflow itself.  I believe that StackOverflow uses Lucene.NET for search; does it use a stock analyzer, or has it been heavily customized?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/analysis/WordDelimiterFilterFactory.html ? It's for Solr but you could use the same technique to define how you want to split up the tokens...

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best to use the WhitespaceTokenizer and customize it to strip off punctuation. For example we strip of all puncutation except '+', '-' so that words such as C++, etc... are left but opening and closing quotes and brackets, etc are left. In reality though for something like this you might have to add the document twice using different tokenizers to catch the different parts of the document. i.e. once with the StandardTokenizer and once with a WhitespaceTokenizer, in this case the StandardTokenizer will split all your code, e.g. between class and method names as the Whitespace one will pick-up the words such as C++. Obviously it kind of depends on the language though as e.g. Scala allows some punctuation characters in method names.